# Cancel or Interrupt runOnUiThread(Runnable) [Android]

Tags: java, android, multithreading

At the core, my Android application consists of navigating between panels that fetch and display content. Each panel calls `fetchContent` on a background thread, and then after the content is fetched, `fetchContent` calls [runOnUiThread(`displayContent`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) , to display the content. When the user switches panels, an event called `panelSwitch` is called.

If the user switches panels before the content is fetched, then `panelSwitch` cancels/interrupts `fetchContent`, which in turn handles the interruption by not calling `displayContent`. However, I was thinking that if there is stuff already happening on the UI thread when the user switches panels, then `panelSwitch` is pushed to the back of the event queue. Then, if the background thread finishes fetching the content before `panelSwitch` reaches the front of the queue, then `runOnUiThread(displayContent)` will push `displayContent` to the end of the event queue, after `panelSwitch`. This means that the UI will switch panels and then the content from the previous panel will be displayed, which is wrong.

Is there a way to cancel/interrupt `displayContent` like I do with `fetchContent`?

Comment: Try using `removeCallbacks(displayContent)`, called on some `View`. This works for `postDelayed()`; I expect that it will work with `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: `removeCallbacks()` applies to `Handler`s, doesn't work for `runOnUiThread()`. Should I switch to a `Handler` for my background thread?

Comment: `removeCallbacks()` applies to `Views` as well: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed If `removeCallbacks()` is not working for you for your `Runnable`, switch to `post()` called on a `View` (or a `Handler`, if you happen to have one for other reasons).