# Is there a way to speed up touch/click detection?

Tags: android

I have been working on a game where speed is required to score well, in the game the user is clicking on objects and using them with other objects which are held in a gridView that's being controlled by an imageAdapter. I have noticed that when I click quite fast some clicks don't register, I have cleaned up the code running when the user clicks but that doesn't seem to be the problem since I tested it just highlighting objects and not running code when clicked and it was just as slow. So is there a way to speed up the click detection, or would this be limited by the speed of the device its self, I have been testing on an htc one m8.

Comment: Are you updating the view status and or style in the same UI Thread you respond to the click event?

Comment: return the UI thread as soon as u can, launch the widget updates with 'runOnUiThread'. Even try to cancel previous updates with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058317/cancel-or-interrupt-runonuithreadrunnable-android . Once the UI thread is freed It´ll respond as soon as the user clicks

Comment: I'm using a onItemClickListener for the gridview to detect the clicks for the objects inside it, this gets the position and the view in that position. I then run the necessary code in that onItemClick event.

Comment: return as soon as posible and launch background tasks for ui updates, try that and see how it responds. It should go faster

Comment: So would I run the code thats in the onItemClick in a different thread? I've never really learnt too much about using multiple threads so this is new to me.

Comment: you should try not to block the UI thread with your handling. There´s only one UI thread and it attends ALL the user events. It should be freed as son as possible. the runOnUIThread is used to queue code for it to run in that Thread whenever it´s idle.

Comment: I'll definitely look into doing this tomorrow, I just read a bit about the different threads and it sounds like the solution, you could post that as the answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return as soon as possible from the handler and run the UI update code in background with 'runOnUiThread()'.

Notice that changing view status MUST be done in the UI thread or the Android runtime will throw an exception. You can work complex calculations in background 'AsyncTask' and call 'runOnUiThread()' from within them whenever you want to update UI components.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do such think. It depends on the speed of your hardware. But what you can do is to use the onTouch listener. In this way you listen only after one action(when it is pressed). for onClick it is registered 2 actions(when u press the button and when u release the button). In this way maybe you could do it faster.

You can also try this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I'm not sure if an ontouch listener would work since I'm currently using an onItemClick listener to detect when the objects are clicked rather than the grid its self.